# Libsvm without kernel

Tags: java, kernel, libsvm

I have searched for quite a long, but I haven't found answer for my question. How can I use LIBSVM in Java without kernel? Or how is it possible to simulate such behaviour?

Comment: It would help if you showed the extent of your research so far; you say you have searched but what paths did you explore, why did they end up being dead ends etc?

Comment: LIBsvm offers 5 types of kernel functions: linear, polynomial, radial basis function, sigmoid, precomputed kernel. First four are obvious, but I don't fully understand the last one. I think that this may be a simulation of what I want to achieve. Here is some description.
http://www.metz.supelec.fr/metz/personnel/frezza/ApprentissageNumerique/TP-MachineLearning/Supervise/libsvm-README.txt
I tried also to find some confirmation, that LIBsvm allows not to use kernel function, but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Kernels are used to map your data to a higher dimensional space. If you  want to perform SVM in the original space of your input data, use the linear kernel.

```
LibSVM classifier = new LibSVM();

classifier.setKernelType(new SelectedTag(LibSVM.KERNELTYPE_LINEAR, LibSVM.TAGS_KERNELTYPE));
```